# How to properly increment this 'half-diamond' shape?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the slashes to form a half-diamond type of shape, but I cannot seem to get the incrementation correct. I currently have:

```
else if (menuOption == 2) {
    
    
    int numberOfDolls = 0;
    cout << "Number of dolls -> ";
    cin >> numberOfDolls;

      
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++) {
      for (int j = 1, n = numberOfDolls; j <= i; j++) 
        cout << setw(n--) << '/' << endl;
      
      for (int k = 1, s = numberOfDolls; k <= i; k++)
        cout << setw(s++) << '\\' << endl;
        
        
        cout << setw(numberOfDolls + 1) << "-" << endl;
      
    
    } 


}
```

This yields the following if the user, let's say, inputs 3:

```
  /
  \
   -
  /
 /
  \
   \
   -
  /
 /
/
  \
   \
    \
   -
```

It should look like:

```
  /
  \
   -
  /
 /
 \
  \
   -
  /
 /
/
\
 \ 
  \
   -
```

I would greatly appreciate any help as I am new to C++.

Comment: Instead of setw(s++), try setw(n++) or setw(++n)

Comment: @OzgurMurat that doesn't change it

Comment: @hyper-neutrino how long does it usually take for some help? jw

Comment: Try OzgurMurat's comment.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I did. Doesn't that not work because s is defined as numberOfDolls within the loop while n is not defined in the loop? therefore I get an error if i change s to n

Comment: `s = numberOfDolls` => `s = numberOfDolls - i + 1`

Comment: @alephalpha ok that worked. Could u explain how u came up with that though i would like to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int numberOfDolls = 0;
    int deltaIndent = 0;
    cout << "Number of dolls -> ";
    cin >> numberOfDolls;



    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++) {

        deltaIndent = numberOfDolls - i;
        for (int j = i; j > 0 ;j--)
            cout << setw(j + deltaIndent) << '/' << endl;

        for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++)
            cout << setw(j + deltaIndent) << '\\' << endl;

        cout << setw(numberOfDolls + 1) << "-" << endl;
    }
```

output

```
Number of dolls -> 4
   /
   \
    -
   /
  /
  \
   \
    -
   /
  /
 /
 \
  \
   \
    -
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
    -
```